# Oracle regexp to split numbers and units

Tags: sql, regexp-substr

I'm trying to extract numbers and units from a input string. I was able to extract the number, but unable extract the units.

```
WITH smpl AS 
(

    SELECT '8.23 ug/dL' str FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT 'negative' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '29.2 ' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '0.2 E.U./dL' FROM DUAL UNION
    SELECT '-150 ng/mL' FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT 
    str, 
    regexp_substr(str, '\.*[[:digit:]]+\.*[[:digit:]]*') num
FROM smpl;
```

desired output:

[image]

Comment: How do you classify the word "negative"?  Absence of a num/units combination so leave both NULL?  Could you have a unit without a num?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT str, 
       nullif(regexp_replace(str, '(-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*) ([^[:digit:]]*)$', '\1'), str) as num,
       nullif(regexp_replace(str, '(-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*) ([^[:digit:]]*)$', '\2'), str) as unit
FROM smpl;
```

The `nullif()` handles the situation where nothing matches -- returning `NULL` rather than the full string.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3f0010dca20b5842426463bbb1be4457) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks @gordon linoff.. Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks again.

Comment: To remove the dash before the leading number put the optional dash in front of the first group:  `-?([0-9]*\.?[0-9]*)`